# Multidimensional Convolution in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, multidimensional-array, signals

I'm trying to convolve a 3 dimensional values array of shape (10, 100, 100) with a gaussian of shape (10, 100, 100). When I use the convolve function I get a Value error.

```
def gaussian(x, mu, sigma):
    g = (1./ (sigma * sqrt(2*pi))) * exp(-(x - mu)**2 / sigma**2)
    return g

gauss_I = gaussian( values, mean(values), std(values) ) 

import numpy as np 
np.convolve( values, gauss_I)

convolve(values, gauss_I)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    convolve(values, gauss_I)

```
  File "/Users/Me/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1013, in convolve
    return multiarray.correlate(a, v[::-1], mode)

ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

I've also used the correlate function but that gives me the same error.

Comment: Please supply the *entire* error message: the trace-back is important to people who know innards of the support packages.

Comment: The docs for `np.convolve` say: `convolution of two one-dimensional sequences`.

Comment: Full stack won't help here.  `convolve` calls `core.multiarray.correlate` right away, and that is `built-in` (i.e. compiled).  This is a usage error - wrong dimensions for the inputs.

Comment: You might want to look at [scipy.ndimage.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html#scipy.ndimage.convolve)

Comment: I've just been looking into that but it makes my kernel crash repeatedly

Comment: That sounds like an independent issue (possibly related to version mismatches between SciPy and NumPy?)

Comment: Scipy has a 2d version: scipy.signal.convolve2d

Comment: I've just made sure I've got the newest updates but it's still crashing when I use, ndimage.convolve(values, gauss_I)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been having the same problem for some time. As already mentioned in the comments the function `np.convolve` supports only 1-dimensional convolution. One alternative I found is the scipy function [`scipy.signal.fftconvolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html#scipy.signal.fftconvolve) which works for N-dimensional arrays.

For example here I test the convolution for 3D arrays with shape (100,100,100)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as sps

# create 3D meshgrid and function cos(x+y)
bins = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(bins, bins, bins)
cos = np.cos(x+y)
print(cos.shape) # (100, 100, 100)

# plot projection of function on x-y plane
plt.title(r'$\cos(x+y)$')
plt.contourf(x[:,:,0], y[:,:,0], np.sum(cos,axis=2))
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')
plt.show()

# perform convolution of function with itself
conv = sps.fftconvolve(cos, cos, mode='same')

print(conv.shape) # (100, 100, 100)

# plot projection of convolution on x-y plane
plt.title('numerical convolution')
plt.contourf(x[:,:,0], y[:,:,0], np.sum(conv,axis=2))
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')
plt.show()
```

I obtain the following images:

[image: cos]

[image: convolution]

Hope it is helpful!